# When to use ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am starting to explore about  ASP.NET Web API.

1. When should we use ASP.NET Web API ?
2. Benefits of it in conjunction with MVC project ?
3. Can we use it even with ASP.NET ?

Comment: Check this out:- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341414/WCF-or-ASP-NET-Web-APIs-My-two-cents-on-the-subjec

Comment: Thanks @RahulTripathi. Will go through this link.